# How to make a nav bar that can move to another views

Tags: swift, xcode

Here is a photo, I need to make this when you click on the right button it is moving you forward and backward for the left one.
[image: img]

Here is the result I want:

[image: img]

The buttons moves you to a different views

Answer (score 1):

I think you can create a view and add label for title also page controller too after that add collection view under view and enable pagination. Use custom nib file for views (screens).